# Add a new element to xml using powershell

Tags: c#, xml, powershell

I have an XML file like given below

```
<xml xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<Product>


<Feature Id="f1" Absent="qqq"  Title="test" Level="1">

  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef1" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef2" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef3" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef4" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="WindowsFolder1" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef5" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef6" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef7" />
  <Feature Id="f2"  Display="hidden">
    <ComponentRef Id="Component1" />
  </Feature>
 <FeatureGroupRef Id ="fg1"/>
</Feature>

       </Product>

</xml>
```

Need to add an element between first Feature tag feature id=f1. The element format  i want to add is given below

```
<ComponentGroupRef Id="Mycomponentname" />.
```

The resultant xml should look like below

```
<Feature Id="f1" Absent="qqq"  Title="test" Level="1">

  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef1" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef2" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef3" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef4" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="WindowsFolder1" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef5" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef6" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef7" />
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="Mycomponentname" />
  <Feature Id="f2"  Display="hidden">
    <ComponentRef Id="Component1" />
  </Feature>
 <FeatureGroupRef Id ="fg1"/>
</Feature>

       </Product>

</xml>
```

I tried the following code for adding the element but it is failing

```
$filePath="C:\Filename.xml"
[xml]$doc=Get-Content $filePath
$x= $doc.CreateElement("ComponentGroupRef")
$x.SetAttribute('id','Mycomponentname')
$doc.Product.Feature.AppendChild($x)
```

The error i am getting  at the last line of code is given below

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the xml tag.

```
$filePath="C:\Filename.xml"
[xml]$doc=Get-Content $filePath
$x= $doc.CreateElement("ComponentGroupRef", $doc.xml.Product.NamespaceURI)
$x.SetAttribute('id','Mycomponentname')
$doc.xml.Product.Feature.AppendChild($x)
```

One note is since it's appended, it'll show up at the end after fg1. Something like this:

```
<xml xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product>
    <Feature Id="f1" Absent="qqq" Title="test" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef1" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef2" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef3" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef4" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="WindowsFolder1" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef5" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef6" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ComponentGroupRef7" />
      <Feature Id="f2" Display="hidden">
        <ComponentRef Id="Component1" />
      </Feature>
      <FeatureGroupRef Id="fg1" />
      <ComponentGroupRef id="Mycomponentname" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>
</xml>
```

Comment: How are you saving it? Something like this? `$doc.save("C:\Filename.new.xml")`

Comment: yes i am saving it using $doc.save("C:\Filename.xml")

Comment: What about this? `$doc = $doc.OuterXml.Replace("xmlns=\`"http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi\`"", "")`

Comment: no Ben,it's not working. I only want to remove the xmlns=" " from <ComponentGroupRef id="Mycomponentname" xmlns="" /> and not from the root.Thanks Ben for helping me

Comment: I got it correct by using $doc=[xml] $doc.OuterXml.Replace(" xmlns=`"'`", "")

Comment: Apologies, I totally missed that the element got the extra xmlns. I was very confused as to why you wanted to drop it from the root. Glad it's working.

Comment: No Problem. You are great :-)